# How to Create A Delegate to Listen to All Text Boxes on a Form

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

I am learning about event handlers and delegates.  I have a single form with 4 text boxes and a list box.  I'd like to have a delegate that listens for text box changes to ANY of the 4 boxes.  The method associated with the delegate would simply be a method that takes the text value of the text box that changed, and add that as a new list item.  My question is how to write the delegate to listen to all of the text boxes, and when I call the function to add the list box item, how can I pass in the text box object since I won't know explicitly which one raised the event?  Will this be contained in the EventArgs e?

Rather than use multiple event handlers:

```
this.textBo1.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
this.textBo2.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
this.textBo3.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
this.textBo4.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
```

I'd like something like:

```
public delegate ListenToTextBoxes(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Maybe that doesn't make sense since I'm new to delegates, but it seems reasonable to me that I should be able to make one delegate listen to text box controls in general, and then when it raises the event I cast the object sender and get the text box text.  But how do I create the delegate so it listens ONLY to text boxes, or other types of controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```
// form constructor
public MyForm()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.textBo1.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
   this.textBo2.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
   this.textBo3.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
   this.textBo4.TextChanged += txt_TextChanged;
}

// event handler
void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
   this.myList.Add(textBox.Text);
}
```

**EDIT :**
(according to the question update)

Actually, the previous code can easily modified to created one single delegate and pass it to all the textboxes, but it doesn't change too much (there're still four event subscriptions):

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // EventHandler is defined as:
    // delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // so its signature is equal to your delegate:
    // delegate void ListenToTextBoxes(object sender, EventArgs e);
    // Hence, if you receive that delegate from somewhere out, you can pass it
    // to TextChange events
    var myDelegate = new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);

    this.textBox1.TextChanged += myDelegate;
    this.textBox2.TextChanged += myDelegate;
    this.textBox3.TextChanged += myDelegate;
    this.textBox4.TextChanged += myDelegate;
}
```

The problem is that you do need to subscribe the `TextChanged` event for each `TextBox` control, there's no *magic way* to say "register all the TextBox.TextChange events to this delegate".
But, if you are sure that all the textboxes that you want to register are children of this control, you can use a loop, e.g. :

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var myDelegate = new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);
    foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        var txtBox = ctrl as TextBox;
        if (txtBox != null)
            txtBox.TextChanged += myDelegate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, casting the sender object makes sense.  What I'm still after is the ability to create a single delegate to respond to all text boxes, rather than multiple lines of adding event handlers.  Can I do something like:<br/>    public delegate ListenToTextBox(TextBox textBox);

Comment: @spickles: Mmh, I don't understand... a delegate is, let's say, a pointer to a method. Here you're passing 4 delegates pointing to the same method. Well, if you will you can create one handler only and pass it to the 4 events but it doesn't change too much. Anyway, probably I'm not getting the point, could you give more infos, like pseudo-codes or so? (edit the main question)

Comment: @spickles: BTW, I'm assuming you're using WinForms, is it correct ?

Comment: @spickles: Edited. I hope it helps. BTW, is by chance your delegate passed from somewhere out of your form ?

Comment: Looks good.  I can do that.  I am not delegating outside the form.  I am assuming I'll have to use Threading and some classes/objects to store data between forms if that were something I wanted to do?  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @spickles: multithreading + forms have to be managed carefully. I suggest you to use the BackgroundWorker class to avoid a lot of problems with threading in winforms ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use "sender". Here's an example:

```
textBox1.Click += AllTextBoxes_Click;
textBox2.Click += AllTextBoxes_Click;

void AllTextBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    tb.Text = "Clicked here";
}
```

Due to updated question:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Listen(this);
}    

void Listen(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl2 in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl2 is TextBox) (ctrl2 as TextBox).TextChanged += tb_TextChanged;
        foreach (Control ctrl3 in ctrl2.Controls) Listen(ctrl3);
    }
}

void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do things...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might intuit the other answers that `sender` is the object raising the event (one of your four text boxes once the event is attached to `Click`), however for an in depth explanation of determining the sender I'd suggest [HOW TO: Determine the Sender of an Event Without Using the Control.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457091.aspx)